# How can i data display based on selection of fields immediately, without refreshing the page?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the email addresses dynamically after the selection of the checkboxes as you can see in the image. These emails will be stored in "mailRecipients". So, what i want to do is, as soon as i end selecting both the checkboxes, i should get the email addresses in the recipients field, from the response from my service.
[TS] Component:

```
      this.adminService.admincomposeEmail(finalEmailObj).subscribe((data: any) => {
            $('.customLoader').hide();
            var res = data.response;
            this.mailRecipients = data.data;
            console.log(this.mailRecipients)
            if (data.status) {
                Swal('Success!', res.msg, 'success');
                // this.router.navigate(['/admin/messaging']);
            } else {
                Swal('Oops...', res.msg, 'error');
            }
        });
```

[HTML]This is my field for the recipieints

```
<div class="c-field u-mb-small">
  <label class="c-field__label" for="subject">Recipients</label>
  <input 
    class="c-input" 
    type="text" 
    name="mailRecipients" 
    [(ngModel)]="mailRecipients" 
    placeholder="Subject">
</div>
```

[image]
Check this Image. Here once i select user type and country how can i display the email addresses immidiately?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any stackblitz sample to reproduce this issue?

Comment: i tried to bind it with the value using ngModel but it needs to reload for it

Comment: When you load your component just fetch all the required data and filter them according to the selection.

Comment: we do rhe selection after the component is loaded

Comment: we are getting the email address dynamically

Comment: @pratyushkumar, you'll have to provide way more information than that to clearly point out what you're trying to achieve here. Things like your minimal component code etc.

Comment: @SiddAjmera please check now, if it is understandable

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but here's the idea that you can create an array, push the 'Name' into array on checkbox change event when checked, then join the array and assign it to model
something like this

```
model: any;
arr: Array<string> = new Array<string>();
```

change event of checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="change($event, 'Vendor')">

change(event, name) {
    if ($(event.currentTarget).is(":checked")) {
    this.arr.push(name);
  }
else{
    let index = this.arr.indexOf(name);
    this.arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
    this.model = this.arr.join(', ');
}
```

and your textbox

```
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="model" />
```

For select all, you already have data into 'mailRecipients', add a check for select all and create comma-separated string and pass it to model.